# Start another activity by clicking a button

Tags: android, button, android-activity, onclick

So heres my problem. I set up a button that when clicked should open a new activity but when it is clicked I receive an error: Unfortunately "app_name" has stopped working
my logcat says :Fatal Exception Main

So heres my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="Monday"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Tuesday" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Wednesday" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Thursday" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Friday" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Saturday" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Sunday" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
           android:text="Edit"
           android:onClick="mondayintent" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
           android:text="Edit" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button3"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
           android:text="Edit" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button4"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
           android:text="Edit" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button5"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
           android:text="Edit" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button6"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
           android:text="Edit" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button7"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
           android:text="Edit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the second Xml to which im trying to reach in another activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="Monday" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="3"
        android:inputType="time" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="3"
        android:inputType="time" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

      <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/profileSelector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="3" 
        android:prompt="@string/profile"
        android:entries="@array/profileSelector"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally the code that supports both:

```
package com.example.hush;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      Intent clickedDay;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
        Button mondayEdit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    public void mondayintent()
    {
        clickedDay= new Intent(this,Monday.class);
        startActivity(clickedDay);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

second activity code:

```
package com.example.hush;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Monday extends Activity{           

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.monday);
    }
}
```

Below I have added my android-manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hush"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hush.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.hush.Monday"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.hush.Monday" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>            
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Comment: [Start a new Activity on a button click](http://themasterworld.com/in-this-lecture-we-will-see-how-to-start-a-new-activity-on-a-button-click-in-the-current-activity/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to call another activity like this inside the OnClickListener() of button

```
Button mondayEdit= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mondayEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, secondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);      
                finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: but instead i used an android:onClick in the xml

Comment: But you didnt add the "View v" as arguments.   public void mondayintent(View v) {//Your code here }

Comment: @user2613577 : If you feel the answer helped you please accept it.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Probably your code is showing error due to Android manifest file, Try  adding proper class in manifest file.
 Making first activity as main , and other as default.Others part of code is exactly fine.

Comment: I added a manifest for you to check it out ... thanks alot for taking time to look over this post :D

Comment: change this line    `<action android:name="com.example.hush.Monday" />`    to  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MONDAY" />`